# Why does getActivity() work when updating a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 2 simple xml files, one with a `<fragment>`, `<EditText>`, and `<Button>` and another with a `<TextView>`.

For my two classes, my MainActivity sets up the onClickListeners for the button to send the input from the EditText to the other class, FragmentActivity, via a bundle.

My FragmentActivity looks something like this:

```
public class FragmentActivity extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment, container, false);


    Bundle input = this.getArguments();

    if(input != null) {

        String message = input.getString("msg");

        TextView fragText = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fragment_text);

        fragText.setText(message);
    }

    return V;
}
```

}

Initially, I had my fragText looking like this:

```
TextView fragText = (TextView) V.findViewById(R.id.fragment_text);
```

and the result was that the text would never update. What exactly is going on here?

Also, when you replace a fragment with a View in code, does this mean that you can treat your main_layout.xml as if it had no `<fragment>` and instead had something else (like a `<TextView>`)?

**Edit**: Sorry, it probably wasn't smart not to post the rest of the files in question.

activity_fragment.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.test.android.testfragapp.FragmentActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_text"
        android:text="This is a fragment."
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment
        class="com.test.android.testfragapp.FragmentActivity"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_holder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        tools:layout="@layout/activity_fragment"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_text"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_display_regular"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Click to display"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_display_reverse"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Click to reverse"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // removes the shadow from the action bar for lollipop devices
        if(Integer.valueOf(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT) >= 21)
            getActionBar().setElevation(0);

        final EditText input_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_text);

        this.findViewById(R.id.button_display_regular).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("msg", input_text.getText().toString());
                placeFragment(bundle);
            }
        });
    }

    // Replace the fragment with the activity_fragment layout
    public void placeFragment(Bundle bundle){
        Fragment fr = new FragmentActivity();

        fr.setArguments(bundle);

        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_holder, fr);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: replacing v.findviewbyid with getActivity() should not work. And, how are you replacing a fragment with a view. What you wish to achieve with it?

Comment: I really have no idea what the hell I was doing now that I think about it. 

What I was trying to do was have some text in the upper portion that could easily be updated with an EditText and a Button, but I just now realized that I could replace the <fragment> in activity_main.xml with a simple <TextView> that could be easily modified with a setText via the onClick method. 

I really have no words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have not posted your xml files I need to guess. Does R.layout.activity_fragment really contain your TextView? From the naming I would think it contains your fragment tag which is then the layout of your Activity so simply the wrong one.

Comment: Yes, it does contain the TextView. It's the activity_main.xml layout that contains the fragment. I'm starting to suspect that I've been doing this incorrectly.

Comment: I see, the problem is that you are trying to replace a fragment at runtime. This does not work with the fragment tag. Fragment tags are static. If you want to replace a fragment during runtime you need to add a layout container (for example a FrameLayout) and replace this one with your FragmentTransaction: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html

Answer (score 0):

We will need to see your XML file to answer this better. We will also need to see how your `Fragment` is being added to your `Activity`, But from what you have posted, it looks like you are inflating what is meant to be an **activity** layout within a **fragment**.

This is not how this is supposed to work. I'm guessing what you want is along the following lines

1. An `activity_main.xml` that contains nothing but your `<fragment>` tag
2. A `my_fragment.xml` that contains your `TextView`s
3. An `Activity` that does `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main.xml)` in its `onCreate()`
4. a `Fragment` that does `View fragView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);` in its `onCreateView()`.

Now, you can do `fragView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_text);`

In short, it looks like you are seeing the weird behavior since you have mixed up the fragment layout and activity layout.

Comment: Updated with all the source files. I hope I haven't been doing this incorrectly...